# Apple Pay On Web - Sandbox Testing

Tags: testing, app-store, app-store-connect, applepay

I have following the steps described in this [link](https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-sandbox/) to perform a sandbox testing. But I was failed to use the sandbox tester that I have created in iTunesConnect. When I tried to login using the tester account in App Store on an iPhone, it prompts the following error. I have verified the apple ID but it still failed. How to resolve it? By the way, is it possible to add a test card to a real apple ID for testing?

[image]

Comment: You  can check my answer at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515789/apple-pay-sandbox-tester-not-able-to-login-into-device-ios-10/40216375?noredirect=1#comment69706701_40216375

Answer (score 3):

The Apple Pay Sandbox account is not for signing into iTunes, but to iCloud.

https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-sandbox/

> Important: If you mistakenly use a sandbox tester account to sign in to a production environment, like iTunes, on your test device instead of your test environment, the sandbox account becomes invalid and can’t be used again. If this happens, create a new sandbox tester account with a new email address.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. I am trying to test Apple Pay (web) in the iOS simulator. I try logging into iCloud in the iOS settings, but get an error message about the username/password being incorrect. I can sign in with it as a general apple id (e.g. at appleid.apple.com) but not as the phone account in the simulator.