# Apple Pay sandbox tester not able to login into device iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, applepay

I'm not able to login into my new iPhone 6s(iOS 10.0.1) with this sandbox account for testing apple way. While able to login into web icloud, itunes and tested on my old iPhone 6+(iOS 10 beta 5).

Everytime try to login into iPhone 6s(iOS 10.0.1) I got this error message.

iTunes account creation not allowed

This apple ID cannot be used with the iTunes Stores at this time. Please try again.

Help me what to do, is this bug from Apple side
[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apple Pay On Web - Sandbox Testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480984/apple-pay-on-web-sandbox-testing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried this many time. And getting same thing as you described. At last i were able to add test credit card for testing apple pay by following these steps:

1. Log out from your itunes and app store
2. Log out from iCloud
3. Change your region(Settings->general->Language and Region) to country which supports Apple pay
4. Now open Wallet app
5. You will be asked to login to iCloud account.
6. Login with your Sandbox Tester account
7. Now add Test credit cards to your account.

To get test credit cards details: You can check the cards details shown in this document: https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-sandbox/

Note: When you add test credit cards, some credit cards detail might get failed in verification, then you have to try another one, Luckily you will be able to add after 3-4 tries.

Comment: What about after 20 tries, should I continue ? (this isn't even a joke :/ )

Comment: Have you tried same one again and again?, see the link given above, you will find many test credit card details and some of them will work depending upon your locale and country

Comment: I tried them all back in December. But it's working properly now, since I updated iOS in early January. But thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't login to iTunes with a Sandbox account.

> If you mistakenly use a sandbox tester account to log in to a production environment, like iTunes, on your test device instead of your test environment, the sandbox account becomes invalid and can’t be used again. If this happens, create a new sandbox tester account with a new email address.